# Integration of Branch.io with Google Firebase in React Native

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-analytics, branch.io, google-analytics-firebase

I need to Integrate Branch.io with Google Firebase Account for one of my mobile apps built in react native so I can be able to Track all my deep links data on Google Firebase or Google Analytics Dashboard. but the issue is the official branch.io documentation only shows the implementation for the native apps (like in Java, Kotlin, or Swift) and not for the React Native apps. I am also attaching the reference link from the branch.io official documentation to provide a better view of what exactly I want.

https://help.branch.io/using-branch/page/firebase

Comment: It's been 18 days but I am still not able to figure out any solution. Please guide me regarding the problem if any one have ever done this sort of thing.